# how to use many condition in aggregate mongo db

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a transactions collection as:

```
{
  _id:ObjecId("5286f7c1f873cc89108b6898"),
  type:"sms",
  amount:NumberInt(1000),
  input_vendor:"a"
},
{
  _id:ObjecId("5286f7c1f873cc89108b6898"),
  type:"sms",
  amount:NumberInt(2000),
  input_vendor:"a"
},
{
  _id:ObjecId("5286f7c1f873cc89108b6898"),
  type:"sms",
  amount:NumberInt(5000),
  input_vendor:"b"
}
```

I want to use aggregate in mongo to count total sms, and total amount each sms type, please help me.
Result as:

```
total_sms_a:2
amount_sms_a:3000
total_sms_b:1,
amount_sms_b:500
```

Answer (score 1):

you a error in transactions collection: _id field is uniq for all documents in collections. select another field to identify sms related to one number.

```
db.transactions.aggregate( {$group : "$aggregation_id", "total_sms" : { $sum : 1 }, "amount_sms" : { $sum : "$amount" } }})
```

The result:

```
   "result" : [
           {
                   "_id" : "your_aggregation_id",
                   "total" : 2,
                   "amount" : 3000
           }
   ],
   "ok" : 1
```

Do you really need to add a suffix to the names of the resulting fields?

Comment: if using your aggregate expression, you can only get total sms, but i want to count with each input_vendor:'a' and input_vedor:'b', eg: with input_vendor:a, total:2, amount:3000, and input_vendor:'b', total:1, account:5000. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$group = array(
  '_id':null,
  'total_sms_mobi'=>array(
            '$sum'=>array('$cond'=>array(array('$and'=>array(array('$eq'=>array('$type','sms')),array('$eq'=>array('$input_vendor','a')))),'$amount',0)
            )
        ),
     )
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to $GroupBy `null` and count `total_sms` and `amount`

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
 {
        $group : {
            _id : null,
            "total_sms" : { $sum : 1 }, 
            "amount_sms" : { $sum : "$amount" }
        }
      }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to group by "$input_vendor", sum +1 to count total sms and sum "$amount" to get total amount. This will get you count and sum for each input_vendor.

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$input_vendor",
            "total_sms": { "$sum": 1 }, 
            "amount_sms": { "$sum": "$amount" }
        }
    }
])
```

If you have documents with other "$type" values, you also have to add a match stage before this group, like this:

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "type": "sms"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$input_vendor",
            "total_sms": { "$sum": 1 }, 
            "amount_sms": { "$sum": "$amount" }
        }
    }
])
```